How recover my solana scam
i text you because someone stall all my solana on my phantom wallet .
I have the adress of the stiler.
(F5tBbLSotLuncMceihuRmnrz7rZPwnW9PuQevM6MNasa)
My adress is actually (EsLtz94iNGZsAq55x5w9ZVrrZtjL8vP9oVyntr4AsgZv)
The amount was : 1.0427sol
Please can you help me .
I need this money…
Sorry for my inglish , I’m French…
Paolo.

I’m sorry to hear about your situation. Unfortunately, cryptocurrency transactions can’t be reversed, so getting the stolen funds back is very difficult. You can use Solscan to check the transaction and save the details as proof. Report the theft to your local authorities and give them the thief’s wallet address(that wouldn’t probably work but you can give it a try). Also, contact Phantom Wallet support to inform them about the issue. To avoid this in the future, make sure your wallet is secure and consider using a hardware wallet for extra safety.
I hope this could help
